# scrapy : different URLs

Tags: python, scrapy

Getting problem in making request to URL. 
While inspecting in the main page I get URL in href as[image]

But when the link gets open , it appears to be :[image]

Both links are different, how can i make request for this.

Here what my shell says:[image]

Comment: maybe the website loading data with AJAX/JS calls, and you should be aware that the data loaded after AJAX/JS calls are not included in original response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `allowed_domains` spider attribute. Your current setting doesn't allow you to follow requests to *jobview.monster.ca* as per log (`DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to ...`). Set that attribute a bit loosely:

```
allowed_domains = ['monster.ca']
```

Comment: Great, though it was not working with 'monster.ca' also because new page started with 'jobview.montser.ca', so I removed the allowed domains. And it worked. Thanks again